# Using jQuery while performing a Fusion Table layer query

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-fusion-tables

I am using jQuery to dynamically populate a drop-down onLoad. I know how to run a query on Fusion Tables v1 but for some reason it returns nothing unless I add the search column twice. As expected, I get the results twice. 
I ran this in jfiddle in order to post this question and it still makes me put the column name in twice but only gives me one set of results.
Admittedly, I don't know much about jQuery but here are my questions:

1. Why do I have to put the column name in twice for the query?
2. How do I run the query and only get one set of results?

Here's the code and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jessegpierce/M35TT/)

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query",
type: "POST",
data: {
    sql: "SELECT Rig, Rig FROM 1owlHA-sxEiMDORsMaX_iTPslRLi1ilhq-AqCda8",
    key: "AIzaSyBuBdRXr2xdoNTJ7xTP_oGi_5zbvT3tPT0"
},
success: function (data) {
    var rigReturn = $("#Operator");
    for (i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
        rigReturn.append($('<option>', {
            value: data.rows[i][0]
        })
            .text(data.rows[i][1]));
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to your numbering within your loop. The option elements are there, they just aren't being displayed correctly.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/M35TT/1/

Change

`.text(data.rows[i][1]));`

To

`.text(data.rows[i][0]));`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see how that fixes the fiddle. For some reason in my working code it still is returning duplicate results. Would you please look at it and see if it's jquery or something else? I just don't understand why I continue to get duplicates. http://northdakotarigsmap.com/workingCopy.html